# Run a 5VDC 0.2A fan from a 24VDC 3.75A power supply - Help Needed

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I am working on a project that is using a 24VDC 3.75A power supply and would like to have a small fan (5V 0.2A) to cool the amplifier and switching circuits within an enclosure. Could someone help with a solution to this, is it as simple as a voltage divider?, if so what size resistors would I need, thanks in advance.

Comment: Voltage dividers are not power supplies. Use a regulator, or buy a 24v fan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some 5V 3-pin regulator in order to lower the voltage, but you will get (24V-5)*0.2A =  3.8W on the regulator (and only 1W on the fan) - this is pretty bad efficiency. The regulator will need heat sink.

Another solution is to use high efficiency switching regulator, but it will make the design over-complex.

So, the best solution is to use 24V fan - it will provide needed function without any additional overhead.

Comment: Thanks johnfound, yes probably easier just to get 24V fan, they're not too expensive, thanks.